# Metadata version mismatch @netbasal/content-loader

Tags: angular, angular-compiler

> ERROR in Metadata version mismatch for module
>   /Users/hardik.shah/git/admin/node_modules/@netbasal/content-loader/content-loader.d.ts,
>   found version 4, expected 3, resolving symbol SharedModule in
>   /Users/hardik.shah/git/admin/src/app/shared/shared.module.ts,
>   resolving symbol SharedModule in
>   /Users/hardik.shah/git/admin/src/app/shared/shared.module.ts

The versions I am using:

```
"@angular/common": "^4.0.0",
"@angular/compiler": "^4.0.0",
"@angular/core": "^4.3.4",
"@netbasal/content-loader": "^1.1.0"
```

Currently I have `@angular/compiler@4.3.0`, I have tried to downgrade `@netbasal/content-loader@1.0.0` but still, I am facing the same issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`@netbasal/content-loader` is not supported for Angular 4. So, there is no option to compatible it with Angular 4. This library is only supported for Angular 5 and 6 as of now.

So, There are two possibilities now:

1. Upgrade to Angular 5
2. Remove `@netbasal/content-loader` library.

I have removed that library from my current project as can't upgrade to Angular 5.